# Getting the number of symbols in a symbol table

Tags: linux, symbols, symbol-table

I'm trying to find the number of symbols an executable defines.  Let's say our executable is called "node"

I'm running

```
nm node
```

on my terminal, and it's outputting a large number of symbols.
I've looked at the man page for nm, along with https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm , but I haven't been able to find something that will simply return a count of the symbols in the symbol table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
nm -an foo | wc -l
```